# How to suppress all images in beamer?

Tags: beamer, graphics

My beamer presentation has lots of images and compiling the PDF takes quite a while. How can I switch off the image generation in beamer?

I have the `demo` option on the `graphics` package, but that leads to an option clash.

Comment: Try `\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}` *before* `\documentclass`. If it does not help, please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964).

Comment: Instead of "switch off" the image generation, if you happen to use PNGs, consider preconverting all your PNGs to PDF and include those.

Comment: The beamer user guide lists a couple of possible options in section "4.3.3 Ways of Improving Compilation Speed". The easiest one `\documentclass[draft]{beamer}`